# Определение пола по ФИО

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, nlp

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм определения пола по ФИО. Может есть на питоне какие-то решения? Я пробовал: 1-по окончаниям;
2-с помощью pymorphy разбивал ФИО на слова и определял род каждого слова.
Есть еще какие-нить библиотеки или может алгоритм? ФИО могут быть не только русские.

Comment: Наверное, хватит и И из ФИО... находите список женских и мужских имен и сопоставляете ему имя. Просто и эффективно :)

Comment: А с иностанными фио как быть? :)

Comment: @gil9red Саша, Женя :)

Comment: @andreymal, Александр, Александра, Евгений и Евгения :)

Comment: Александр Александра Евгений Евгения

Comment: @gil9red а теперь надо ещё умудриться заставить пользователей писать имя именно в таком формате)

Comment: @ss_beer думаю, у них тоже женские и мужские отличаются :)

Comment: @gil9red https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unisex_name :)

Comment: @andreymal если Александр напишет себя как Саша, будет бабой определяться, сам виноват ))) Да и имен в en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unisex_name очень мало, пальцами двух рук перебрать можно, в сравнении с общим количеством имен, просто капля в море :)

Comment: работать будет только с официальными именами. С англ будет сложнее - там есть общие имена

Comment: Ну английских имен мало, но могут быть. Пошел искать словари имен)) или мож кто поделится ссылкой?:)

Comment: вот https://yadi.sk/i/O8T-ZRN6mfbjA (взято отсюда)

Comment: точно эту задачу решить невозможно (начните [здесь](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)). Могут существовать решения, которые приемлемы именно в вашей ситуации (к примеру, пользователь может сам указать пол, если желает).

Comment: Наверно логично по склонению отчества (если оно указано или есть). А имена есть такие что неотличишь. Например  тим может быть как м так и ж. Кроме того нужно отсеять дополнительные "оглы" "ван" и т п.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Мой вариант - это пробегаться по базе данных и спрашивать есть ли совпадения:

Сначала достанем базу данных на этом [сайте](http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/order.php)

В левом окне в шаге 3 выберем Russian (Cyrillic) - в правом я выбираю United States, для генерации укажем только интересующие нас поля: Gender, Given Name и Surname, саму базу сделаем самой большой: 50000

Также давайте закажем для генерации базу и для английских имён по аналогии.

Процесс не быстрый, так что можно пойти заварить чаёк и выкурить сигаретку. Как придём, нам придёт 2 письма со ссылками на скачивание наших БД.

Напишем код:

```
import pandas as pd

dfru = pd.read_csv('FNru.csv')
dfen = pd.read_csv('FNen.csv')

# создадим сеты, чтобы не бегать по одному и тому же item'у

rumalenames = set(dfru[dfru['Gender'] == 'male']['GivenName'])
rumalesurnames = set(dfru[dfru['Gender'] == 'male']['Surname'])

rufemalenames = set(dfru[dfru['Gender'] == 'female']['GivenName'])
rufemalesurnames = set(dfru[dfru['Gender'] == 'female']['Surname'])

enmalenames = set(dfen[dfen['Gender'] == 'male']['GivenName'])
enmalesurnames = set(dfen[dfen['Gender'] == 'male']['Surname'])

enfemalenames = set(dfen[dfen['Gender'] == 'female']['GivenName'])
enfemalesurnames = set(dfen[dfen['Gender'] == 'female']['Surname'])

name = input('Name: ')
surname = input('Surname: ')

if name in rumalenames and surname in rumalesurnames:
    print(name, surname, 'is male')

elif name in rufemalenames and surname in rufemalesurnames:
    print(name, surname, 'is female')

elif name in enmalenames and surname in enmalesurnames:
    print(name, surname, 'is male')

elif name in enfemalenames and surname in enfemalesurnames:
    print(name, surname, 'is female')

else:
    print('Unkown data')
```

Давайте протестируем что у нас получилось на нескольких входных данных:

```
# Name: Никита
# Surname: Токарев
# Никита Токарев is male

# Name: Ольга
# Surname: Соколова
# Ольга Соколова is female

# Name: Жанна
# Surname: Токарева
# Жанна Токарева is female

# Name: Carolina
# Surname: Thompson
# Carolina Thompson is female

# Name: Mark
# Surname: Watson
# Mark Watson is male

# Но решение не идеально, конечно
# Требуется либо очень много данных, либо очень хорошая БД
# И то не факт, что все имена будут включены

# Name: Олег
# Surname: Волоков
# Unkown data

# Name: Ashley
# Surname: Roth
# Unknown data
```

Answer (score 6):

[Можно](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a751ead30d02d52f364c365f166a67c796d436a6/pymorphy2__examples/find_gender_by_first_name.py) воспользоваться [pymorphy2](https://github.com/kmike/pymorphy2) для определения пола по имени:

```
# pip install pymorphy2
import pymorphy2

morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()

name_list = ['Константин', 'Виктор', 'Любовь', 'Дамир', 'Венера', 'Таисия', 
             'Алёна', 'Евгений', 'Егор', 'Никита']

for name in name_list:
    parsed_word = morph.parse(name)[0]
    print('{:<15} {}'.format(name, parsed_word.tag.gender))
```

Результат:

```
Константин      masc
Виктор          masc
Любовь          femn
Дамир           masc
Венера          femn
Таисия          femn
Алёна           femn
Евгений         masc
Егор            masc
Никита          masc
```

---

**PS.** У некоторых имен есть `ё` (например, Алёна), которая часто заменяется на `е`, поэтому такие имена может библиотека неправильно определить. Например, скажет что Алена это мужского пола.

**PPS.** Метод `morph.parse` возвращает список, т.к. у одного слова может выдать несколько вариантов разбора. Например, для `Алена` мне выдало несколько вариантов, и один из них был `Алена`, другой `Алёна`. Поэтому для своего скрипта я [добавлял проверку с заменой `е` -> `ё`](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/048b03a63dd357c19a9f10e6e89c2c01a4165f16/currrent_job_report/print_statistic_number_male_and_female.py#L34).

Answer (score 2):

Также для определения пола по фио можно использовать нейронную сеть. Пример можно взять здесь: https://github.com/Rai220/MlSexDetector

Пример работы:

```
Input name: Владимир Путин
Sex:  М
[[  4.24729733e-05   9.96808589e-01   3.14901001e-03]]
Input name: Любовь Петрова
Sex:  Ж
[[  3.94746803e-06   7.50368787e-03   9.92492378e-01]]
Input name: Полад Бюльбюль оглы
Sex:  М
[[ 0.00102036  0.97395748  0.0250222 ]]
Input name: Кто Где
Sex:  unknown
[[  9.99970675e-01   2.07114244e-05   8.59489865e-06]]
```

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к ответу user243273:

Для более широкой проверки я предлагаю:

1. Искать не точное совпадение фамилии, а проверять по окончаниям фамилий. Таким образом мы расширяем возможные значения фамилий
2. При оценке пола использовать систему баллов: если имя/фамилия женское, то добавляем +1 балл, если мужское - вычитаем -1 балл. В итоге если сумма баллов больше 0, то пол женский, а если меньше 0 - мужской. Таким образом, по имени "Маргарита Маркиросян" или "Саша Иванова" можно определить, что владелец - женщина, несмотря на то, что фамилию "Маркиросян" или имя "Саша" могут иметь как мужчина, так и женщина

```
import pandas as pd

dfru = pd.read_csv('FakeNameGenerator_ru.csv')
dfen = pd.read_csv('FakeNameGenerator_en.csv')

ru_male_names = set(dfru[dfru['Gender'] == 'male']['GivenName'])
ru_male_surnames_endings = set(s[-3:] for s in dfru[dfru['Gender'] == 'male']['Surname'])

ru_female_names = set(dfru[dfru['Gender'] == 'female']['GivenName'])
ru_female_surnames_endings = set(s[-3:] for s in dfru[dfru['Gender'] == 'female']['Surname'])

en_male_names = set(dfen[dfen['Gender'] == 'male']['GivenName'])
en_male_surnames_endings = set(s[-3:] for s in dfen[dfen['Gender'] == 'male']['Surname'])

en_female_names = set(dfen[dfen['Gender'] == 'female']['GivenName'])
en_female_surnames_endings = set(s[-3:] for s in dfen[dfen['Gender'] == 'female']['Surname'])


def is_woman(name, surname):
    woman_score = 0

        if name in ru_female_names or name in en_female_names:
        woman_score += 1

        if surname[-3:] in ru_female_surnames_endings or surname[-3:] in en_female_surnames_endings:
        woman_score += 1

        if name in ru_male_names or name in en_male_names:
        woman_score -= 1

        if surname[-3:] in ru_male_surnames_endings or surname[-3:] in en_male_surnames_endings:
        woman_score -= 1

    return woman_score > 0
```

Пример работы кода:

```
print(is_woman('Лолита', 'Маркиросян'))
# True
```