# Как разделить список имен на мужские и женские

Tags: python, python-3.x, анализ-данных

К примеру есть список

`names = ['Андрей', 'Елена', 'Юлия', 'Роберт', 'Валерия', 'Амбер']`

Как можно из списка записать м. имена в список males, а ж. в список females.

P.S. в данном случае `str.endswith` не поможет, ибо есть много женских имё не оканчивающиеся на А (см. Валерия, Юлия, Амбер)

Comment: как вы получаете данный список?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655179/Определение-пола-по-фио-на-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скачиваешь [отсюда](https://mydata.biz/ru/catalog/databases/names_db) "База данных имен и фамилий в формате JSON.zip" и кидаешь в директорию с основным модулем

```
import json


def json_to_dict(filename):
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        return json.load(f)


def sort(names, all_names, male_names = [], female_names = []):
    for dicti in all_names:
        name = dicti['Name']
        if name in names:
            if dicti['Sex'] == 'Ж':
                female_names.append(name)
            else:
                male_names.append(name)
    return male_names, female_names


def main():
    names = ['Андрей', 'Елена', 'Юлия', 'Роберт', 'Валерия', 'Амбер']
    filename = 'russian_names.json'

    all_names = json_to_dict(filename)
    sorted_names = sort(names, all_names)

    print(sorted_names[0])
    print(sorted_names[1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Результат:

```
['Андрей', 'Роберт']
['Валерия', 'Елена', 'Юлия', 'Амбер']
```

Answer (score 0):

Скачиваете, например, отсюда http://analiz-imeni.ru/women/vse-zhenskie-imena.htm список женских имен. Если очень хочется -  можно и мужские поискать. И пишете скрипт, отбирающий одни и другие. Работы - на час.  Правда со всякой экзотикой типа "Амбер" придется бороться самостоятельно, путем периодического пересмотра-дополнения этих списков.

Comment: А если с использованием чего-то дополнительного, то можно это упростить? Ну там pandas для анализа данных или что-то такое?

Comment: pandas  -  это инструмент. Можно и микроскопом гвозди забивать. У вас задача - найти элементы одного списка в другом списке. Все. Ровно одна команда Python или один цикл, если это надо сделать для всех имеющихся имен. Какой еще более простой инструмент нужен?

Answer (score 0):

> P.S. в данном случае str.endswith не поможет, ибо есть много женских имё не оканчивающиеся на А (см. Валерия, Юлия, Амбер)

С «Амбер» вам метод `.endswith()` не поможет, но с окончанием на `я` да — метод `.endswith()` может в качестве параметра принять *не только одну строку,* но и **кортеж строк**:

```
In[6]: names = ['Андрей', 'Елена', 'Юлия', 'Роберт', 'Валерия', 'Амбер']
In[7]: females = [name for name in names if name.endswith(("а", "я"))]
In[8]: females
```

> ```
> ['Елена', 'Юлия', 'Валерия']
> ```

Comment: А тек-же не поможет с  Айжан, Анаит, Асель,  Бьорк, Гаянэ, Гузель, Жаклин(!!) , Шерил, Чулпан  и кучей других имен, которые могут встретиться.  А также Фома,   Кузьма, Лука, Никита, Иса, Муса, Добрыня, Генри -  как вполне мужские имена.  Поэтому работать "по окончаниям" в данном случае не лучшая идея