# Идентификация пола по именам

Tags: python, pandas, excel, идентификация

Есть база Excel. Один из столбцов список имен.
Стоит задача сделать из списка имен еще один столбец, который добавляет пол напротив каждого имени.
Чтобы далее презентовать статистику по полу клиентов.
Пробую через библиотеку `pymorphy2`, но не работает.
Изучение языка только начал, поэтому могу не понимать где-то логику кода.
Помогите с вопросом, плз
Предыдущая тема определения пола по фио не подходит к решению

```
name_list = df['Manager']

def pol(name_list):
    for name in name_list:
        parsed_word = morph.parse(name)[0]
        table_pol = parsed_word
    return table_pol
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Определение пола по фио на python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655179/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python)

Comment: я взял оттуда идею с библиотекой pymorphy2, но на своем примере не могу реализовать

Comment: @Ivan, а чем именно не подходят решения из "вопроса-дубликата"?

Comment: Он не отвечает на вопрос, как добавить дополнительный столбец после на 500к значений с определением пола

Comment: @Ivan так задавайте вопрос относительно "как добавить дополнительный столбец", а не второй подряд дубликат "Идентификация пола по именам"

Comment: @Ivan, уточните суть вопроса. Вопрос в том как добавить столбец со значениями  или в том как идентифицировать пол человека по имени?

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Друзья, сорри. Когда задаешь вопрос, он кажется очевидным. Мой вопрос, скорее в том, как мне добавить столбец с полом, по имеющимся именам в столбце.

Comment: @Ivan, здесь не приветствуются вопросы-задания в стиле `"дайте воды напиться, а то так проголодался, что переночевать негде"`. Уточните в вопросе с какой частью у вас возникли затруднения - с идентификацией пола по имени и почему вам в этом случае не подошли ответы из вопроса-дубликата или же с добавлением столбца со списком значений?

Comment: ознакомьтесь,поможет https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Не получается добавить отдельный столбец, с определённым с помощью библиотеки pymorphy2 полом по имени из другого столбца.

Answer (score 2):

Добавить новый столбец к Pandas DataFrame очень просто - присваиваем столбцу с новым именем список значений такой же длины как и количество строк во фрейме:

```
In [156]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3], "b":[4,5,6]})

In [157]: df
Out[157]:
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

In [158]: df["new"] = [12,13,14]

In [159]: df
Out[159]:
   a  b  new
0  1  4   12
1  2  5   13
2  3  6   14
```

NOTE: вместо списка можно использовать одномерный вектор numpy.ndarray или Pandas Series.

---

PS для того, чтобы **определить пол человека по имени**, советую воспользоваться одним из ответов, данных на [вопрос "Определение пола по ФИО"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655179).

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогли. Буду искать на других ресурсах.

Comment: @Ivan, помощь придет очень быстро как только вы начнете следовать простым правилам форума и научитесь правильно задавать вопросы! :) В любом случае, желаю удачи!

Answer (score 0):

Python отложите в сторону для более сложных задач
Используйте формулу

```
=ЕСЛИ(ПРОПИСН(ПРАВ(A2;1))="А";"жен.";"муж.")
=IF(UPPER(RIGHT(A2;1))="А";"жен.";"муж.")
```

Ошибки, безусловно, возможны, но при достаточно большой выборке результат не должен существенно повлиять на статистику.

Суть фокуса в том, что придумать женское отчество не заканчивающееся на "а" довольно сложно. В исходных данных они могут появиться в виде опечаток.

Comment: отчеств нет, только имена...

Comment: Тем не менее, способ может сработать. Если учесть Любовь, Нинель и Нелли, то буквы "а" и "я" помогут определиться с полом