# Как проверить на какую букву заканчивается строка в Python?

Tags: python

Например пользователя просят ввести имя своего друга или подруги, и как узнать, указал он друга или подругу? Очевидно что если имя заканчивается на -а или -я значит друг это девушка, а если на другие буквы то значит друг это мальчик.

Comment: Саша и Женя это мальчик или девочка? А еще есть Жасмин, Нелли

Comment: Пусть вводят с отчествами - тогда -ович мальчик, -овна девочка. Ну за редким исключением

Comment: А так - [str.endswith](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/operatsii-tekstovymi-strokami-str-python/metod-str-endswith/) или через срезы

Comment: Можете сюда заглянуть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655179/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a4%d0%98%d0%9e

Comment: Вова, Петя и Вася, я так понимаю, девочки.

Comment: Что то не логично. Лучше запрашивать пол отдельно и не париться с этим. Ну если вам нужен последний символ то `data[len(data) - 1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить символ строки можно обращением к элементу по индексу, индексация начинается с нуля. Пример:

```
f_name = “Толик“  # пример строки
print(f_name[0])  # это первый символ(Т)
print(f_name[1])  # это второй символ(о)
print(f_name[-1])  # это последний символ(к)
```

А вот определение пола пользователя только по строке имени не будет корректно отрабатывать в некоторых случаях (прим. Женя, Саша).
Ручного выбора пола, в любом случае, избежать не получился.

Как вариант, который будет отрабатывать часть очевидных имен - хранить имена в списках. В случае совпадения введенного имени с именем из списка - пол будет установлен автоматически. Если имени в списке нет - запрос ручного выбора пола.

Исправлено:

Довольно интересный вариант предложили в комментариях к вопросу. Можно обязать пользователя вводить отчество, это может покрыть основное количество кейсов. Но для тех, у кого отчества нет, похоже, все равно придется запрашивать ввод пола вручную)